# Is there a reason that .str.split() will not work with '$_'?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to split a string using .str.split('$_') but this is not working.

Other combinations like 'W_' or '$' work fine but not '$*'. I also tried .str.replace('$*') - which also does not work.

Initial string is '$*WA*:G_COUNTRY'

using 
ClearanceUnq['Clearance'].str.split('$_')
results in [$*WA*:G_COUNTRY]
no split....

whereas 
ClearanceUnq['Clearance'].str.split('$')
results in [, *WA*:G_COUNTRY] 
as expected

Comment: *does not work* . What does it say? Is there any error? Which python version are you using?

Comment: _Other combinations like 'W\_' or '$' work fine but not '$'_ I'm confused.  Does `$` work, or not?

Comment: Thanks for your response - for some reason the text editor body changed ('$_') to ('$'). Which then presents my question as rubbish leading to the comments. This perhaps offers some insights into the issue I have experienced. My string is dollar sign underscore eg ''$_WA:G_COUNTRY''. when I use .str.split('$_')  to split the string it simply doesn't split the string result for the above is '[$_WA:G_COUNTRY]' - I have use split many time with many combinations and never had an issue. I'll guarantee this does not work.

Answer (score 2):

This is because it is trying to split the string when it finds a `$` AND a `_` right next to eachother, which does not occur in your first string.